# Change background colour BEHIND ViewController frame (when frame.origin is altered)?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, frame, uiviewanimation

I have an app which intakes client details, built for iPad. When the user taps a `UITextField` towards the bottom half of the `ViewController`, the `frame` programatically shifts upwards so that the fields aren't hidden behind the keyboard. (I tried to implement a `UIScrollView` but just cannot seem to get it working.) The slight issue I'm having now is when the `frame` shifts up, you can vaguely see the black behind it. This isn't a huge issue because I have changed the animation time and the black background is barely visible, but I have a feeling there is a more elegant solution.

Here is my code to shift the `frame`:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    // Animate frame up if lower textfields are tapped
    if (([textField isEqual:_emailField]) || ([textField isEqual:_dobField]) || ([textField isEqual:_niNumField])) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil
                    context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.35f];
        CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
        frame.origin.y = -210;
        [self.view setFrame:frame];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    } else {
        // Return frame to original position if other textfields are tapped
        [self dismissKeyboard];
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)dismissKeyboard {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil
                        context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.15f];
        CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        [self.view setFrame:frame];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Here is a brief screenshot of what I'm trying to describe. Left picture is the `ViewController` normally, right picture is when the `frame` has been shifted upwards. You can see (vaguely) almost in line with the second row of characters is where the `frame` stops.

[image: Left: Normal frame. Right: frame.origin.y altered]

I realise this doesn't seem like an issue because it is barely visible at all, but I have had to speed up the animation hiding the keyboard or else the `frame` drags behind and the black background becomes visible. I am wondering: is there a way to change this colour? Or is that something we don't have access to? If anyone can suggest a more elegant method for what I am trying to do, I'd gladly take a better solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `UIViewController`'s view is added to the main `UIWindow`. So you should be able to achieve what you want by changing the `UIWindow`'s background color.

In the `UIApplicationDelegate`:

```
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

However, what you're doing isn't the best way to solve the problem of the keyboard covering up the text fields. You should use a `UIScrollView` or a `UITableView` to manage this view and use content insets to shift the view up or down.

Comment: Using your code I was able to successfully change the `window` colour to white. This solves the immediate issue, thanks! I will look into `UIScrollView` again and try to implement it. Thanks for your help :)